# How Can I accept date string and format in typescript?

Tags: typescript, date, oracle-jet

I am getting a date in a string format as `20160229000000 ('YYYYMMDDhhmmss')`. 
I have to accept the string and display in `DD-MON-YYYY` format using Typescript.

I don't want to use an angular package (DatePipe) as I am doing it in OJET.

Comment: Can you use regex to get the different parts of the date, and return a new string based on the regex capture? Do you need even need an actual Date object?

Comment: Yes I want use it in UI also

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use substrings and a map for months names.

```js
const format = (value: string): string => {
  const year = value.substr(0, 4);
  const month = value.substr(4, 2);
  const day = value.substr(6, 2);
  const months = {'01':'JAN','02':'FEB','03':'MAR','04':'APR','05':'MAY','06':'JUN','07':'JUL','08':'AUG','09':'SEP','10':'OCT','11':'NOV','12':'DEC'};
  return day + '-' + months[month] + '-' + year;
};

format('20160229000000'); // 29-FEB-2016
```

Comment: is there any package or library for the same?

Comment: Try momentjs. It’s the most popular.

Comment: Let me know if you need an example how to use it - I can update my answer to include it too.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring the OJEt package I choose to use IntlConverterUtils.dateToLocalIso which accepts the sting and gives me the flexibility to use in TypeScript.

```
let dateString = '20160229000000';
let date = IntlConverterUtils.dateToLocalIso(new Date(dateString.substr(0, 4) + '-' + dateString.substr(4, 2) + '-' + dateString.substr(6, 2)));

datevalue(new Date(date).toShortFormat());
```